# Editor that will jump to a given character based on position from EOF?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, elisp, vi

Anybody know of an editor with a command that will jump your cursor to a given byte/character based on it's position to the end of the file (EOF) instead of the beginning of the file?

Something tells me that VI/VIM can do it but my Google-fu is failing me at the moment.

Comment: I find that's unclear. Can You give an example of behaviour You seek? That's certainly can be done with couple of elisp lines.

Comment: Do you need to count the line separator bytes? E.g. if you have two lines, "123" and "456", then would the 4th character from the end be the 3, or somewhere between the 3 and the 4?

Comment: Invisibles count, yes.  I have a datafile specification that talks about values that are N bytes in from the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun go-to-nth-from-eob (n)
  "Go to the Nth character from the end of the buffer.
Interactively, N is the numeric prefix argument."
  (interactive "p")
  (goto-char (- (point-max) n))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs can do this.

To move to the `n`th character in the file, you can use [`goto-char`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Motion.html#index-goto_002dchar-2712). So if you want to go to the 1234th character, run `M-x goto-char`, and in the following prompt, you can type `1234`.

But it doesn't work for going to the `n`th character from the end. Luckily, we can write a method!

```
(defun goto-char-from-end (characters-from-end)
  "Goes to the end of the buffer, then steps characters-from-end characters back."
  (interactive "Nhow many characters back? ")
  (end-of-buffer)
  (backward-char characters-from-end))
```

This can be used the same way, with `M-x goto-char-from-end`. Also like `goto-char`, you can use prefix arguments: type `C-1 C-2 M-x goto-char-from-end`, and it will go to the twelfth character from the end without prompting you.

To load this code into Emacs, copy it into a buffer, then put your cursor after the last parenthesis, and type `C-x C-e`. That runs the code, and puts the function in the currently-running Emacs. If you like it and want to have it forever, the way to do that is to put it in your init file.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, using `(end-of-buffer)` or `(beginning-of-buffer)` generates a message (or at least it used to) stating that it is primarily for interactive use.  The most common way of doing this non-interactively is `(goto-char (point-max))` or `(goto-char (point-min))`.

Comment: And don't use `backward-char` to get there. Just use `(goto-char (- (point-max) characters-from-end))`. (Of course, you probably also want to check that the arg is not greater than `point-max`.)

Answer (score 1):

Vim

Lets say you want to go to the 13th character from the end of the file. Press:

```
G$13<C-h>
```

Details:

`G$` - go to last character in the buffer
`13<C-h>` - go left 13 characters, going over line breaks (`<C-h>` is `Ctrl+h`)

Instead of the `<C-h>` key you can also use `<left>` if you've enabled it with the `whichwrap` setting.

Comment: Note that `<Left>` will not go over line breaks by default, whereas `<BS>` (i.e. `<C-h>`) will. See `:help whichwrap` for more details.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda true, I had that one stuck in my .vimrc for ages, forgot about it

Answer (score 1):

The following Vim mapping will make `[count]gO` behave like `[count]go`, but backwards from EOF:

```
nnoremap <silent> gO :<C-u>execute "normal!" (line2byte(line('$') + 1) - 1 - v:count) . "go"<CR>
```

`line2byte(line('$') + 1) - 1` is the number of bytes in the buffer, and `v:count` is the given `[count]` (defaults to 0, so `gO` is equivalent to `G$`).

Comment: +1 Great idea! Only needs `<silent>` and `normal!` to make it perfect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `<silent>`; I couldn't figure out that `:silent execute ...` wasn't having the desired effect because `:silent` doesn't apply to the mapping itself.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative with Emacs is to advise `goto-char` so that it interprets negative arguments in a natural way:

```
(defadvice goto-char (before interpret-negative-argument activate)
  (when (and (called-interactively-p)
             (> 0 (ad-get-arg 0)))
    (ad-set-arg 0 (+ 1 (buffer-size) (ad-get-arg 0)))))
```

Now you do eg. <kbd>C-u</kbd>`-10`<kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to jump to the tenth character from the end.

Note that I've used `buffer-size` rather than `point-max` to mirror the way `goto-char` usually works with narrowing.